# Import cv2 error: Symbol not found: _av_buffer_default_free

Tags: python, macos, opencv, anaconda, dylib

I'm getting this weird runtime (I think) error with cv2 (assumingly) and cannnot resolve it.
i'm using python3.7 on mac:

```
(proj) user@user-MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop/proj/controllers$ python 
Experiments/n_Experiment.py
pybullet build time: Dec 10 2021 09:53:34
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Experiments/n_Experiment.py", line 1, in <module>
    from experiment import Experiment
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/proj/ontrollers/experiment.py", line 1, in     <module>
    from simulation import LinkServer as SimServer
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/proj/controllers/pybulletsim/simulation.py", line 11, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/proj/lib/python3.7/site-   packages/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _av_buffer_default_free
Referenced from: /Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/proj/lib/libavformat.58.dylib
Expected in: /Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/proj/lib/libavcodec.58.dylib
in /Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/proj/lib/libavformat.58.dylib
```

So far, I've tried to update conda, and all of the following actions which did not help:

update conda navigtors

symbolyc link

> ln -s libavformat.58.dylib

reinstall opencv in various ways (using conda, pip3, brew (also tried to brew build from source).

reinstall numpy (there might be a connection apparently).

Any ideas how to resolve it??

Thanks!

Comment: `Symbol not found: _av_buffer_default_free` what did you do? remove everything, clean everything up. then _only_ `pip3 install opencv-python` and hope that does it. that's the official release. opencv packages from conda/conda-forge are either slightly stale, or seriously stale or untrustworthy.

Comment: I ended up deleting recreating the environment. After creating a new env, I used 'conda install conda,' and then installed only opebcv-python forge. that fixed the problem. I assume that the problem actually caused due to multiple NumPy versions I had on this environment (I found an errno path to NumPy metadata  after runnung so exceptions, not sure what or why though). Conda's default version works fine. 
Thanks!